# javascript to go back pages

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am using the code below. This works at the moment, but say the users leave information that needs to be filled in and clicks confirm as it redirects to the same page and shows the error. but if they were to press the cancel button at this point then the users goes back to the previous form which he filled out, if he then presses cancel on that page goes back to the initial page, how would I use this method to select the first page that it had and not the previous?

```
javascript:history.back()
```

Comment: Instead of checking the first page why don't you add some checks if the user clicks the `Cancel` button since that seems to be where the hole in your code is...?

Comment: I want to go back to the initial page where the create button is if they click cancel.. so i wasnt to go back the number of times the redirect has happened to the same page.

Comment: also, If you just want to go to a specific page.. do this..
`<script>
location.href="http://www.newlocation.…
</script>`

Comment: As i am using data from database to render i need a pasific id which i cant get on the url

Answer (score 1):

You can use the go() method to go back twice, or manipulate the browser history in a way that any error showing page will not create a history entry.
You have to count how many pages you want to ignore an call

```
window.history.go(-3);
```

See here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: DasKrümelmonster answer for only FX ,and cross browser for backing to history of js code -> window.history.back({n}),{n} - equals is step of history.For exp :window.history.back(-1).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any code handy, but I find it best to store the initial location either in a hidden field or a cookie, then use DJ KRAZE's suggestion.  That way you have complete control over where you intend to go upon an error or cancel or whatever.